# jQuery 1.8 postion not working correctly

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am using the jQuery 1.8 position feature to position a div's top left to another div's bottom left like this:

```
$("#aDiv").position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "left bottom",
    of: "#someDiv"
});
```

When data is entered, the div being position will expand downward to encapsulate all the data. However, if the height of the window is too small to hold the entire div being positioned, then the information in the div will expand upward. I want the information to expand downward and never expand upward. How do i stop the div from expanding upward?

Comment: jQuery's current version is 1.7.2. Did you mean jQuery UI or development version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery 1.8 and jQuery UI. You need to use jQuery UI 1.8.22 or higher
http://blog.jqueryui.com/2012/07/jquery-ui-1-8-22/

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have fixed the issue. I needed to set collision to none:
`$("#aDiv").position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "left bottom",
    of: "#someDiv"
});`

(sorry, I cannot figure out how to format the code correctly)